# How to adjust the spacing between items inside a Flutter ListView Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

How can I decrease the spacing between trailing, title / subtile & leading items inside a ListViewTile Widget in Flutter?

[image: listTile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a new property added to the ListTile, which is doing the job:

```
horizontalTitleGap: value(double),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
```

is helping a little to decrease the padding between the ListItems in the row

Answer (score 0):

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

This will help you to solve your error. This is happening cause the subtitle is overflowing the container width. So make the container width the line I above mention.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The Container is inside a side drawer, so taking the full width would destroy my layout..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Flexible Widget in your ListView items

Comment: I tried with no effect. What helped a little is to put the trailing icons with a Wrap Widget and put a negative spacing value..